# gRPC Java Client - hasNext during onNext?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have a server-side streaming gRPC service that may have messages coming in very rapidly.  A nice to have client feature would be to know there are more updates already queued by the time this onNext execution is ready to display in the UI, as I would simply display the next one instead.

```
    StreamObserver< Info > streamObserver = new StreamObserver< info >( )
    {

        @Override
        public void onNext( Info info )
        {
              doStuffForALittleWhile();
              if( !someHasNextFunction() )
                   render();
        }
    }
```

Is there some has next function or method of detection I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API to determine if additional messages have been received, but not yet delivered to the application.

The client-side stub API (e.g., `StreamObserver`) is implemented using the more advanced [ClientCall](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ClientCall.html)/ClientCall.Listener API. It does not provide any received-but-not-delivered hint.

Internally, gRPC processes messages lazily. gRPC waits until the application is ready for more messages (typically by returning from `StreamObserver.onNext()`) to try to decode another message. If it decodes another message then it will immediately begin delivering that message.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to have a small, buffer with messages from onNext.  That would let you should the current message, and then check to see if another has arrived in the mean time.